# 1D hydrostatic equilibrium with Fipy

Tags: fipy

I am trying to implement the compressible Euler equations including a full energy equation in Fipy. In the code below, I aim to obtain a hydrostatic solution (dp/dz = -rho g) in the presence of gravity. However, the code does not seem to do the job properly. I am not sure what could be wrong with these boundary conditions:

```
import fipy
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

#system of units (relative to CGS): 
# user specified units
unit_length = 1.e8 # cm
unit_numberdensity = 1.e9 # cm^-3
unit_temperature = 1.e6 # K

# constants
He_abundance = 0.1 
mp = 1.67e-24 # g
kB =  1.3806488e-16 # erg K^-1
miu0 = 4*np.pi
gamma=5./3.
R_sun = 6.957e10/unit_length # cm
a = 1.0 + 4.0*He_abundance
b = 2.0 + 3.0*He_abundance
g = 2.74e4 * pow(R_sun,2)/(pow(x+R_sun,2))*unit_length/unit_velocity**2; g.name='g'
T_ini = 1.e6/unit_temperature # in K 
# derived units
unit_density = a*mp*unit_numberdensity 
unit_pressure = b*unit_numberdensity*kB*unit_temperature
unit_velocity = (unit_pressure/unit_density)**0.5
unit_time = unit_length/unit_velocity
scaleheight = (T_ini/g.value) #in cm
dens0 = 1.e-15/unit_density # in g cm^{-3}

L = 1.e10/unit_length # in cm
nx = 1000
dx = L/nx
mesh = fipy.Grid1D(dx=L / nx, nx=nx)

x = mesh.cellCenters[0]
x.name='x'
    
dens=fipy.CellVariable(mesh=mesh,value=dens0*np.exp(-mesh.cellCenters[0]/scaleheight), hasOld=True)
dens.faceValue.constrain(dens0, mesh.facesLeft)
dens.faceValue.constrain(dens.value[-1], mesh.facesRight)

mom = fipy.CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=0., hasOld=True)
mom.faceGrad.constrain(0, mesh.facesLeft)
mom.faceGrad.constrain(0, mesh.facesRight)

gradpL = g.value[0]*dens.value[0]/(gamma-1)
gradpR = g.value[-1]*dens.value[-1]/(gamma-1)

Eth = fipy.CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=dens.value*T_ini/(gamma-1), hasOld=True)
Eth.faceGrad.constrain(gradpL, where=mesh.facesLeft)
Eth.faceGrad.constrain(gradpR, where=mesh.facesRight)
      
divv=(mom/dens).arithmeticFaceValue.divergence

eq_continuity = (fipy.TransientTerm(var=dens) 
            == - fipy.ConvectionTerm(coeff=mom*[[1.]]/dens, var=dens)
                ) 
eq_momentum   = (fipy.TransientTerm(var=mom) 
            == - fipy.ConvectionTerm(coeff=mom*[[1.]]/dens,var=mom)
              - (gamma-1)*Eth.grad.dot([[1.]])
              - fipy.ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=g,var=dens)
                )
eq_eth        = (fipy.TransientTerm(var=Eth) 
            == - fipy.ConvectionTerm(coeff=mom*[[1.]]/dens,var=Eth) 
               - fipy.ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=divv,var=Eth)*(gamma-1)
                )

eqn = eq_continuity & eq_momentum & eq_eth
     
viewer = fipy.viewers.matplotlibViewer.matplotlib1DViewer.Matplotlib1DViewer(vars=(dens, mom/dens*unit_velocity/1.e6, Eth*(gamma-1)),
                    datamin=-0.2, datamax=0.6,legend='upper left', title = '1D hydro solution')
viewer.axes.legend([r'Density ($10^{-12}\ \mathrm{kg\ m^{-3}}$)',r'Velocity ($\mathrm{10\ km/s}$)',r'Pressure (0.03 Pa)'])
viewer.plot()

steps=10000

# 60% of maximal sound speed in the domain
cflcond = 0.2 * dx/np.max(np.sqrt(gamma**2*Eth.value/dens.value))
timeStepDuration = cflcond
t=np.arange(steps)*timeStepDuration
    
solution=np.zeros((3,steps,len(x.globalValue)))

for step in np.arange(steps):
        Eth.updateOld()
        dens.updateOld()
        mom.updateOld()
        eqn.solve(dt=timeStepDuration)

        if rank==0:
            if step%50 ==0:
                print('done step',step, ', time', step*timeStepDuration*unit_time)
                viewer.plot()
            solution[0,step,:]=dens.globalValue
            solution[1,step,:]=(mom/dens).globalValue
            solution[2,step,:]=Eth.globalValue
        
            if (step%500==0) & (step != 0):
                np.savez_compressed('savefile'+str(step).zfill(int(np.ceil(np.log10(steps+1)))), solution[:,step-500:step,:])
```

I am expecting the 1D system to reach equilibrium, which does not seem to happen.

Comment: Can you point me to the equations that you are using? I can identify most of the terms from the [conservation form on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)#Conservation_form_3), but not all of them. For instance, what exactly is your expression for pressure? Also, please state mathematically what boundary conditions you want. The BCs you have now are algorithmic and circular, so it's hard to tell what they should represent.

Comment: This conversation will probably be easier to have on [Discussions](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/discussions). StackOverflow isn't intended for back-and-forth conversations and GH Discussions makes it easier to write math.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Discussion moved to: https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/discussions/996